# Marginal density functions

Tags: probability-distributions

Given a disc with center at origin and radius one, where

$$f(x,y) = 1/\pi$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} =1$$

the marginal density function of $X$ is $$2/π * \sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Can the marginal density function of $Y$ be extrapolated without calculation and taken to be the same over $x=1$ and $x=-1$, or is it equal to $2/π$ ?

Comment: Shouldn't $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$?

Comment: By symmetry of the disk, X and Y have the same PDF.

Comment: but is it still correct to say that the marginal density function is equal to 2/pi?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why it would be equal to $2/\pi$?